# How do I find the offset of a matching string using RE2?

Tags: c++, regex, re2

[RE2](http://code.google.com/p/re2/) is a modern regular expression engine available from Google. I want to use RE2 in a program that is currently using gnuregex. The problem I have relates to finding out what matched. What RE2 returns is the string that matched. I need to know the offset of what matched. My current plan is to take what RE2 returns and then use a `find` on the C++ string. But this seems wasteful. I've gone through the RE2 manual and can't figure out how to do it. Any ideas?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Store the result in a `re2::StringPiece` instead of a `std::string`. The value of `.data()` will point into the original string.

Consider this program. 
In each of the tests, `result.data()` is a pointer into the original `const char*` or `std::string`.

```
#include <re2/re2.h>
#include <iostream>


int main(void) {

  { // Try it once with character pointers
    const char *text[] = { "Once", "in", "Persia", "reigned", "a", "king" };

    for(int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
      re2::StringPiece result;
      if(RE2::PartialMatch(text[i], "([aeiou])", &result))
        std::cout << "First lower-case vowel at " << result.data() - text[i] << "\n";
      else
        std::cout << "No lower-case vowel\n";
    }
  }

  { // Try it once with std::string
    std::string text[] = { "While", "I", "pondered,", "weak", "and", "weary" };

    for(int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
      re2::StringPiece result;
      if(RE2::PartialMatch(text[i], "([aeiou])", &result))
        std::cout << "First lower-case vowel at " << result.data() - text[i].data() << "\n";
      else
        std::cout << "No lower-case vowel\n";
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Just what I needed. Thanks. Was this in the documentation? I coudln't find it.

Comment: I didn't find the answer explicitly listed, but I was able to infer it from http://code.google.com/p/re2/source/browse/re2/re2.h#290.

Comment: I need to do exactly the same, except that I cannot modify my regex to add capturing parentheses. How can I know position of partial match in that case?